# My webpage taking too much time while reload

Tags: html, wordpress, web, hosting, pagespeed

I have three websites that i hosted in a shared hosting. The websites are loading fast in first time. But when you trying to reload the page, it took up to 40 seconds. I reinstalled databases, themes, plugins, i deleted the whole site and reinstalled again but nothing changed. Also i tried different browsers, did some pagespeed and gtmetrix analysis but its still sucks when i reload. I opened a ticket to hosting provider and they said there's nothing wrong with our servers. I'm using LiteSpeed server with PHP 7.2. There's a lot of system resources so theres nothing wrong about it. As a newbie, what could be the problem?

Here's my website https://yazilimcilarinmolayeri.com

Note: if i did any English mistakes, please forgive me. I'm from Turkey.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: If you are using the LiteSpeed Cache plugin try disabling it, clear all cache and see if that helps. I had a similar problem with my litespeed hosting and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried disabling CloudFlare and it worked. Idk maybe cloudflare's caching system and the plugin's cache overlapped. So yeah, my problem solved. Thank you for all your help guys.

Btw i activated cloudflare again and its working well for now.

Answer (score 0):

Although your website is working fine right now, this usually happens when you have cached resources, but I'm not sure as to why.

The browser recognizes that a resource is cached and it checks with the server if it needs to be updated. This checking might sometimes take too long (again i'm not sure why) and the browser sometimes won't timeout the request, meaning the page is still waiting for the response to be received.

As @Buttered_Toast mentioned, try clearing your cache, and that should fix it.